# results in commutative algebra that use spectral sequences

Tags: reference-request, spectral-sequences

I am trying to convince my professor to spend some time on the Grothendieck spectral sequence in class(she asked us what we want to do in the last weeks).  She told me that she needs a result that would force the class to learn about spectral sequences.

My background is in homotopy theory so I don't know the answer to the question that I am asking.

What are the results in Commutative Algebra that would force us to learn about spectral sequences?